# Fetch cause undefined index outside the PHP (PDO)

Tags: php, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main_list.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="./add_task.js" defer></script>
        <title>Main List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container">
       <button id="buttonMainList"><a href="./logout.php">Logout</a></button>
          <p id="userNameHere"><?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?></p>
      </div>
      <h1 id="inform">TO DO LIST</h1>
      <div id="add_task_form">
        <button id="add_task">Add New Task</button>
        <form id="add_form" name="task_form" method="post">
            <div id="title_form">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="description_form">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="due_date_form">
                <label for="due_date">Due Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="due_date" id="due_date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"><br>
            </div>
            <div id="time_form">
                <label for="time">Time</label>
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" placeholder="hh:mi"><br>
            </div>
                
                <input id="submit_add_form" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
        <br>
      </div>
      <table border="3" cellpadding="5" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($allTask as $value){?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $value['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['title'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['description'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['due_date'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['time'];?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a problem. I want to display (fetch) all the tasks related to the user and put it into table format. But I don't know why the code generates an error said that:

> Notice: Undefined variable: allTask in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/list-32/main_list.php on line 82
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/list-32/main_list.php on line 82

Can someone help me to fix the error?

```
<?PHP
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$owner = $_SESSION['name'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$due_date=$_POST['due_date'];
$time=$_POST['time'];
$state=0;
$insertQuery="INSERT INTO tasks (owner, title, description, due_date, time, state)
VALUES (:owner, :title, :description, :due_date, :time, :state)";
$preparedInsertStatement = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':title', $title);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':description', $description);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':due_date', $due_date);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':time', $time);
$preparedInsertStatement->bindValue(':state', $state);
$valueInsert=$preparedInsertStatement->execute();
if($valueInsert){
    echo 'Insert is done';
}
else{
    echo 'Insert is not successful';
} 
$displayQuery="SELECT * FROM tasks where owner=':owner'";
$displayTask= $conn->prepare($displayQuery);
$displayTask->bindValue(':owner', $owner);
$allTask=$displayTask->execute();


  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Do you have your first script run after the second one, that is where `$allTask` is defined.  I also see that in your first script you have `$preparedInsertStatement`, which seems to contradict the error message.

Comment: I did change $preparedInsertStatement to $allTask in the HTML. However, the problem still there

Comment: The main problem is still there though, `$allTask` is only defined at the end of the second script, not sure how this information is supposed to get to the first one.

Comment: I did put the HTML script under the PHP script in the same file name task.php

Comment: It's also only set when inside the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: As you see, in the code I did place it inside the if(isset($_POST['submit']))